# Openshift deployment-config template fails to deploy pod if a volume is declared

Tags: templates, openshift

I have an OpenShift deployment configuration template that I generated from a working deployment (using "oc export"). The original pod has a persistent volume claim (PVC) mounted on /data. When I try to deploy using the template, the pod never starts up. If I remove all mention of the volume and volume mount from the template, the pod does start. I then have to manually attach the volume. I want to be able to do it all from the template though. Here is the partial template showing only relevant items:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: myapp
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    name: myapp-service
  spec:
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: myapp-service
          image: my-private-registry/myapp-service:latest
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data
            name: volume-001
        volumes:
        - persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
          name: volume-001
```

When deployed with this template, the deployment sits waiting for the pod to be created ("Status: Container creating"). If the `persistentVolumeClaim` item is replaced with an ephemeral volume declaration:

```
        volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: volume-001
```

it starts up fine. So it seems that the problem is specific to the `persistentVolumeClaim` entry. Both the PV and PVC were set up beforehand, as shown here:

```
> oc get pv
NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STATUS    CLAIM                 REASON    AGE
nfs-pv00     50Gi       RWX           Bound     my-project/nfs-pvc              1h

> oc get pvc
NAME         STATUS    VOLUME     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
nfs-pvc      Bound     nfs-pv00   50Gi       RWX           1h
```

EDIT: Another data point (that perhaps I should have started with) is that if an existing deployment configuration is modified from the openshift console (Applications->Deployments->my-dc) by selecting "Attach storage" and specifying the PVC, the same behavior is observed as with the templated deployment: a new deployment launches (due to config change) but its associated pod never starts.

Comment: What do you get for ``oc get pvc``? If you have quotas on number of persistent volumes you can use, and have claimed your quota, it will sit there in pending state if template is structured in way that it would need to claim a new volume. If you do have maximum claimed volumes, but not using them, you should release them first.

Comment: I added the outputs in the edited OP above. I don't see a mention of any quota and I only have this one (nfs-pv00) and another for container registry (in a different project). So I don't think I've reached a limit.

Comment: If this is a cluster you have set up, there would be no quotas. I only mention quotas in case were using the OpenShift Online developer preview, which has a quota of 2 persistent volumes per user.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: My bad. I discovered that I had a bad mount point on the NFS server that I had set up to serve the PV. Once I specified the correct mount point, the pods started up fine (well, on to the next problem anyway).